# Cocoa Crash Reporter Framework

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, crash-reports, crash-dumps

It seems most of the crash reporting frameworks are no longer maintained:

UKCrashReporter
ILCrashReporter
SmartCrashReporter

The only thing that does seem to be maintained is plcrashreporter. But I'm looking for a framework that just gives me the crash log generated by os x itself, and not an in-process crash reporting framework like this.

Are there any out there that support 10.6-10.8?

Comment: iTunesConnect gives you the crash reports for apps sold through the Mac App Store for free. If you're happy with all the obvious implications of selling through the MAS, that is..

Comment: @Jay - thanks, but I'm also selling non-MAS apps.

Comment: What is the problem of them not being maintained any more? The concept is pretty straight forward and still working if you are not interested in support sandboxed apps.

Comment: Almost everybody these days (HockeyApp, JIRA, etc) are using plcrashreporter as a base.   If you aren't using the sandbox, you can go and dig them out yourself and send them to a server (I did that previously), but if you use sandboxing (which you can do optionally for non-MAS apps), you're going to need to use one of the systems that captures the reports directly at the crash site, instead of from the system crash logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iTunesConnect gives crash reports but only after you reach a certain threshold, and that threshold seems to be quite high, because no one I know has ever received one.  [FeedBackReporter](https://github.com/tcurdt/feedbackreporter) is an option but it too has not been updated in a while.  Last time I checked, though, it worked on 10.8.

The best option I've found is [HockeyApp](http://hockeyapp.net). Pricing starts at 10 USD / month but it does crash report symbolication on the server and its compatible with the MAS as long as you sign the executables and have the entitlements configured correctly. For me its worth the money.

Comment: Interesting option, though it seems to use plcrashreporter.

Comment: PLCrashReporter based solutions are the only way to go if you want to have the feature in a sandboxed app.